# Display tooltip on dynamically added dropdown items

Tags: jquery

Seeing the title of the question, the first instinct in the readers mind would be that it is a duplicate question – but it is not. I have referred the following and a dozen other posts about displaying tooltip in dropdown list.. They work for statically added items.

[How to add tooltips to dropdownlist items, using jquery?](http://webneed.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-add-tooltips-to-dropdownlist.html)

But I have a scenario in which dropdown items are added dynamically in second dropdown based on selections on the first. The tooltip appears for the first but not on the second.

Note: The website needs to support `IE6+`, `Chrome` and `Firefox`

**Code**

```
<html>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () 
{


//Tooltip for all dropdowns
$("select").each( function ()
{ 
    var i =0; 
    var sel = this;
    for(i=0;i<sel.length;i++)
    {   
        sel.options[i].title = sel.options[i].text;    
    }   
}); 




 //Dropdown Change Event

 $("#ddlColor").change(function() 
 {


 //Remove existing entries from dropdown
 $('#ddlExample').empty();
 var n = $(this).val();


 switch(n)
 {

 case 'green':
   $('#ddlExample').append($('<option></option>').val('Mango').html('Mango'));  
   break;

 case 'red':
   $('#ddlExample').append($('<option></option>').val('Apple').html('Apple'));  
   break;

 case 'blue':
   $('#ddlExample').append($('<option></option>').val('Blueberry').html('Blueberry'));  
   break;

 }

 });

});

</script>

<body>

<div id="first">

<select id="ddlColor">
   <option value="green">Green</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select> 


Sample:
<select id="ddlExample">
</select> 


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: i think `$('#ddlExample').attr("title","Mango");` might be what you are looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attr / prop to do that:

```
var option = $('<option></option>');
switch(n){
   case 'green': 
       option.val('Mango');
       option.html('Mango');
       option.attr('title','Mango');
       break;
    //and so on
}
$('#ddlExample').append(option);
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LJANW/